# Why JPA JDBC lock each other in one transaction?

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, transactions, spring-transactions

**Issue with `@Transactional` annotation causing lock conflict when renaming a table**

1. **Scenario**:

   I'm performing two operations within a single transaction:

   1. Saving data to a temp table using **`jpa`**.
   2. Renaming the temp table with **`jdbcTemplate`**.

   I found that the temp table was blocked by the first operation, meaning the renaming couldn't obtain the necessary lock to complete. This has left me puzzled.

   **Code**:

   ```java
   @HandlingTime
   @Transactional
   public void updateFromLocalFiles(@NotNull String materialFile, @NotNull String... statusFiles) {
       saveDataToTempTable(materialFile, statusFiles);
       checkDataIntegrity();
       backupAndDeleteOriginTable();
       replaceTemporaryToOriginTable();
       dropExpiredTable();
   }
   ```

   *saveDataToTempTable* call this *jpa function*

   ```
   protected long saveAllToTempTable(List<AdwMaterialTemp> materialList) {
       List<AdwMaterialTemp> adwMaterialTemps = adwMaterialTempRepository.saveAllAndFlush(materialList);
       return adwMaterialTemps.size();
   }
   ```

   *replaceTemporaryToOrigiinTable* call this *jdbc function*

   ```
   public void changeTableName(String originTableName, String targetTableName) throws DataAccessException {
       String RENAME_TABLE_NAME = "ALTER TABLE %s RENAME TO %s;";
       var sql = String.format(RENAME_TABLE_NAME, originTableName, targetTableName);
       jdbcTemplate.execute(sql);
       log.info(SQL_LOG, sql);
   }
   ```

I see this in processList in database:

```
| 9289 | root            | 172.20.0.1:63024 | sephora-product-management | Query   |   1240 | Waiting for table metadata lock | ALTER TABLE adw_material_temp RENAME TO adw_material |
```

in performance_schema.metadata_locks:

```
| OBJECT_TYPE       | OBJECT_SCHEMA              | OBJECT_NAME                                  | COLUMN_NAME           | OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN | LOCK_TYPE           | LOCK_DURATION | LOCK_STATUS | SOURCE            | OWNER_THREAD_ID | OWNER_EVENT_ID |

| TABLE             | sephora-product-management | adw_material_temp                            | NULL                  |       140332151913120 | SHARED_WRITE        | TRANSACTION   | GRANTED     | sql_parse.cc:5737 |            9352 |          15429 |
| TABLE             | sephora-product-management | adw_material_temp                            | NULL                  |       140331681928000 | EXCLUSIVE           | TRANSACTION   | PENDING     | mdl.cc:3702       |            9353 |             19 |
```

I delete the transactonal annotation. Then it works.

Comment: What is your database, and how does it handle DDL statements within transactions? DDL is not generally transactional; not all databases like and support table manipulation while data is using a table.

Comment: I use mysql:8.0.22. And the autocommit config is on.

Comment: If you don't have a transaction, your JPA write operations won't go to the database at all. Try turning on SQL logging and you'll be able to see what is going on with your various options. Mysql automatically commit DDL statements, so they are NOT within the transaction, and they cannot be rolled back, so I don't know what you are hoping to accomplish, but you are better off doing something different like issuing the DDL after the transaction is successful (outside of the method marked with the transaction annotation) or at the beginning.